# Is there any way for an android app to know which device its installed on?

Tags: android, tablet

Suppose I wanted to target a specific few Android devices (e.g. tablet), is there any means for an app to know which device its installed in? I mean I would like the app to know what kinds of features the device has, for example, front facing camera, screen resolution, etc. It would be best to be able to know the exact device the app is working in as it would help make the app actually usuable ;).

If that sounds ridiculous, as an Android developer can you specify when you publish your app which device(s) you want the app available in?

I guess ultimately I could write in capitals EXCLUSIVE TO or AVAILABLE IN "insert device name" in the app description.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to design an app for a tablet, you should be looking at the screen size.

You can find out the screen size with Resources.getConfiguration().screenLayout:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Note your first decision there is going to be whether you consider a tablet to be the size SCEENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE or both XLARGE and SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE.  (Note XLARGE is introduced in Honeycomb; you can find the constant in the preview SDK.)

If you want to limit which devices will see your app on Market, you can use the supports-screens tag to specify which screen sizes you are compatible with.  For example

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" />
```

More information on screen sizes is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
String s="Debug-infos:";
s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
s += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
s += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
s += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't think there would be such a good solution. Does this work in all android devices?

Comment: Yes, its a built in part of the Android OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has solved a major obstacle. I haven't done android development before, so not so familiar with the API. Could I impose on you to ask about the second part of my question, can I choose which devices can install my app?

Comment: You can take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

I know you can restrict it per device features (i.e. does it have a camera/compass) but I'm not entirely sure by actual device type.  I haven't tried it before, sorry :-\

Comment: Filtering by features should be a good enough. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you are wanting to find out if you are running on a tablet, that is not a good solution AT ALL.  In fact, that is 99% a horrible solution.  Please don't use anything except android.is.Build.VERSION_SDK for deciding behavior; none of the other fields have a well enough defined meaning for programmatic use like that.